# Masking Credit Card Number Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-masking

On my javascript

```
<script>
$("#inputCardNo").keydown(function(e){
if(e.keyCode != 8){
var length = $(this).val().replace(/ /g,"").length;
if(length < 12){
   var val = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < length + 1; i++){
      val+="*";
    if((i+1)%4 == 0){
        val+=" ";
      }
   }
   $(this).val(val);
}
if(length < 12 || length >= 16){
    e.preventDefault();       
}
}
});
</script>
```

Here's the live action of this [JS FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pqkqvr7x/)

What I want here is that the first 4 digits will also be unmasked. I've been struggling with my own logic. Could someone point it out to me?

Comment: Do you mean you want the last 4 to also be masked? or the first 4 to be unmasked?

Comment: Why are you using Javascript to mask the credit card number?

Comment: @JoelBanks unmasked i mean let me edit

Comment: @EdHeal I use javascript because of it fits ??

Comment: What is the motivation to mask the credit card number when the person is entering the number?

Comment: I don't quite get it, sir. I'm sorry but I used this because I need to hide the middle numbers for security?

Comment: Have you typed in a credit card number into a web site. You need to double check it. It is quite a few digits to get right. It does not help that you cannot check the number

Comment: But it what the most customers want sir. I couldn't contradict what they want. :(

Comment: Are you sure about that? It is common practice to be able to enter in the full credit card number and be able to double check it. See Amazon, Ebay, ....

Comment: I am sorry, but it seems initial 12 digits are getting masked

Comment: @EdHeal While they are typing sir they can see it before it masked that what is my problem also

Comment: Personally and others read the number off the card and type it in. Then re-read the number and check.This is in conjunction with the code at the back as well as expiry back along with the name on the card.

Comment: And please stop calling me Sir

Comment: Sorry @EdHeal. Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follow:

For masking all digits except the first 4 and last 4

```
function maskCreditCard(inputString) {

    // Mask all digits except the first 4 and last 4
    let maskedString = inputString.replace(/\d/g, (match, index) => {
        return index > 3 || index < inputString.length - 4 ? '*' : match;
    });

    return maskedString;
}
```